# When we get the error Explicitly define the missing copy assignment operator .., do we need to define only the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, sonarqube

**I am getting the below error from SonarQube for my C++ application at ~TestQueue(); destructor
Explicitly define the missing copy assignment operator so that it will not be implicitly provided.**

To resolve that error I explicitly defined the assignment operator:

**Is it sufficient to define only assignment operator as per the error message ? or do I need to define copy construcor, move constructor, and move assignment operator also?**

```
class TestMessage
{
public:
    TestMessage();
    ~TestMessage() {}
};

class TestQueue
{
private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::queue<TestMessage*> tstQueue;

public:
    ~TestQueue();
    TestQueue();
    TestQueue& operator= (const TestQueue &tQueue);
};

TestQueue::TestQueue()
{
}

TestQueue::~TestQueue()
{
    if (!tstQueue.empty())
    {
        while (tstQueue.size())
        {
            tstQueue.pop();
        }
    }
}

TestQueue& TestQueue::operator = (const TestQueue &tQueue)
{
    if (this == &tQueue)
        return *this;

    tstQueue = tQueue.tstQueue;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Rule of five: If you need one of them (destructor in your case), you should specify all of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: That destructor only slows things down and you don't need it. The queue will be cleared by the default destructor.

Comment: I didn't understand how the "tstQueue" will be cleared by the default destructor.

Comment: Who owns  the objects pointed to by the elements of your queue? Do you expect your destructor to delete them? Because as written, it does not (and if it did, your copy constructor and assignment operator would actually have to copy the objects to prevent different queues from deleting each other's items).

Comment: Hi @seepp2k, I am expecting that the destructor delete tstQueue by calling tstQueue.pop(); And as you suggested, please help me whether destructor deletes the different objects that we are creating using copy assignment operator?

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder `tstQueue` is a member of the object, it can't be deleted individually (you can't delete part of an object). I'm asking whether you want to delete the objects pointed to by the elements of the queue and who owns them. Or to approach this from a different angle: Why are the elements of the queue pointers, where do they point to and which other pointers in the program are expected to point there (and for how long relative to the lifetime of the queue)?

Comment: I am not sure whether we need to delete the objects pointed by the elements of the queue. But, We are accessing queue and TestMessage members from other classes also.